# Mysqli query array data manipulation

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a php page that calls for data from an sql database and displays it on a table.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['first_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['last_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><a href=\"javascript:win1({$row['formID']})\">Activities<a/></td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><a href=\"javascript:win2({$row['formID']})\">Awards<a/></td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['total']}</td>"; 
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['date']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['IP']}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

is my current code, but I want to know if there is a way to fetch a certain number row
like fetching the 32nd row in the result instead of fetching from 0 to the end?

Comment: When fetching the 32nd row, do you need the others before? Otherwise you could use LIMIT 32,1 in you SQL Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data_seek in mysqli to do just that

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Something";
if ($result = $mysqli->query( $query)) {
    // seek to row number 32
    $result->data_seek(31);
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    //use the $row data
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: if I do data seek then loop through with fetch array, will it start from row 31 to the end of the result?

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php this function (or method) will move the result pointer, in other words, if you fetch after it, it will use seek row as a starting point, if you want to start from somewhere else just reuse it with another row

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT` in SQL Query Like `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT x, n` this will start from the x+1th row and will select n rows...

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECT` statement, add a [`LIMIT`](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) clause like so: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ... LIMIT 31, 1`. This will select only the 32nd row from the table. You can replace `31, 1` with any range you want.

This works best if you add an `ORDER BY` clause so the rows always come out in the same order.